# JButton in a JEditorPane

Tags: java, swing, object, jbutton, jeditorpane

http://weblogs.java.net/blog/aim/archive/2007/07/embedding_swing.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/index.html?javax/swing/text/html/ObjectView.html

I add html code to JEditorPane:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
    <html>
      <body>
          <table width="90%" height="90%" align="center">
              <tr align="center">
                  <td align="center">
                      <object classid="javax.swing.JButton" label="just do it">
                      </object>
                  </td>
              </tr>
          </table>
      </body>
    </html>
```

[image]

How can I control this button? (Change size, color, add listener e.t.c)

I solved the problem, a working example:

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit;
    import javax.swing.text.ViewFactory;
    import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
    import javax.swing.text.Element;
    import javax.swing.text.html.ObjectView;
    import javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument;
    import javax.swing.text.View;
    import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;

    import javax.swing.text.*;
    import javax.swing.text.html.HTML;
    import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit;
    import java.net.URL;

    public class EditorPaneTest extends JFrame
    {
public EditorPaneTest()
{
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationByPlatform(true);        

    JEditorPane editPane = new JEditorPane();
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(editPane);     

editPane.setContentType("text/html");
editPane.setEditable(false);
    editPane.setEditorKit(new CompEditorKit()); // install our hook

editPane.setText("<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\">"+
"<html>"+
"<body>"+
"<object classid=\"javax.swing.JLabel\" label=\"just do it\">"+
"</object>"+
"</body>"+
"</html>");
    add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    setSize(400, 300);
    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String... args)
{
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            new EditorPaneTest();
        }
    });
}
protected class CompEditorKit extends HTMLEditorKit {
    @Override
    public ViewFactory getViewFactory() {
        return new CompFactory();
    }       
}   
protected class CompFactory extends HTMLEditorKit.HTMLFactory {
    public CompFactory() {
        super();
    }
    @Override
    public View create(Element element) {
        AttributeSet attrs = element.getAttributes();
    Object elementName = attrs.getAttribute(AbstractDocument.ElementNameAttribute);
    Object o = (elementName != null) ? null : attrs.getAttribute(StyleConstants.NameAttribute);
    if (o instanceof HTML.Tag) {       
            if ((HTML.Tag) o == HTML.Tag.OBJECT) {
                return new CompView(element); 
            }
        }
        return super.create(element);
    }
}   
protected class CompView extends ObjectView {
    public CompView(Element element) {
        super(element);
    }
    @Override
    protected Component createComponent() {
        Component component = super.createComponent();  // COMPONENT IS CREATED HERE
    System.out.println(component);
    JLabel layeredPane = (JLabel)component;
    layeredPane.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("images/9.gif"))));
    return component;   
    }
}
    }
```

But now another problem. I can not get the Jlabel coordinates
System.out.println(layeredPane.getLocation()+ "|"+layeredPane.getSize() +"|"+ layeredPane.getY());
Return 0 0 0

Comment: I didn't know about this `classid` thing. That's interesting. Unfortunately it seems that, other than setting some bean attributes, there is nothing you can do to those instanciated components. And I can't find a way to get a reference to this instance afterwards. The code presented in your first link (where she extends `HTMLEditorKit`) allows you to have a total control on how to represent an HTML element, from here you can control the aspects and listeners of your button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be this could help
http://java-sl.com/custom_tag_html_kit.html

About coordinates. The JLabel is placed in a container. Size and bounds are set during layout/paint of the pane's content.

When all content is properly visible you can get the label's parent container and use getBounds() to obtain real bounds.

Answer (score 5):

This won't answer your question, but it may help you if all you want is to have a button that reacts to clicks in a `JEditorKit`.

The trick is to use an HTML form, and use a different URL for each button. Then, a HyperlinkListener will react on button clicks, where you can dispatch your events based on the content of the URL.

```
    JEditorPane ed = new JEditorPane();
    ed.setContentType("text/html");
    HTMLEditorKit kit = (HTMLEditorKit) ed.getEditorKit();
    HTMLDocument doc = (HTMLDocument) ed.getDocument();
    doc.setBase(new URL("http://fakeurl.com"));
    kit.setAutoFormSubmission(false);
    ed.setText("<html>"
            + "<head>"
            + "</head>"
            + "<body>"
            + "  <form action='http://fakeurl.com:1'><input type='submit' value='hello 1' /></form>"
            + "  <form action='http://fakeurl.com:2'><input type='submit' value='hello 2' /></form>"
            + "</body>");
    ed.addHyperlinkListener(new HyperlinkListener() {
        public void hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkEvent e) {
            System.err.println(e.getURL().getPort());
        }
    });
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(NimbusLookAndFeel.class.getName());
    JFrame f = new JFrame("test frame");
    f.setContentPane(ed);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setSize(1024, 768);
    f.setVisible(true);
```